# Can the preposition 'in' be used before the noun 'abroad'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can the preposition *in* be used before the noun *abroad*? Can I write the following sentence: *Your friend in abroad?*

Comment: No, it can't. *in* is a preposition, and *abroad* carries within it a preposition of it's own: *a-*. You can say *My friend abroad emailed me.* Or, *My friend *in* Austrailia emailed me.* (A sentence needs a verb.) But not *in abroad*. It would be like saying *My friend in in Australia.*

Comment: @Kris - one of my most common (and embarrassing) errors. I honestly know the difference. My fingers just rebel.

Answer (score 0):

***[abroad](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abroad)*** *adverb*

> **1**. in or to a foreign country or countries.

The definition of *abroad* already includes the preposition *in* or *to* according to context. As such no more preposition is needed.

> Your friend <strike>in</strike> abroad …

Comment: The question asks about the noun, not the adverb.

Comment: @Clare Think again. The adv. is for explaining the point. The answer is about the noun.

Answer (score 0):

The writer and secretary of the Bank of England Kenneth Grahame writes in *The Golden Age* (1895):

> She was somewhere over in that beastly abroad.

*In that beastly abroad* is a prepositional phrase, as is *in abroad*. So, structurally there is no valid argument against using the preposition *in* before the noun *abroad*.

Using *abroad* as a noun is acceptable and the OED provides the following examples, among others:

> ‘Frogs’, he would say, ‘are slightly better than Huns or Wops, but abroad is unutterably bloody and foreigners are fiends.’

(Nancy Mitford, *The Pursuit of Love*, 1945)

> He likes abroad and he loves foreign travel.

(Sir Nicholas Henderson, *Old Friends and Modern Instances*, 2000)

Of course, *your friend in abroad* is not a sentence, as you state. But English is robust enough to permit a sentence such as

> Your friend in abroad is starting to miss home.

This is 100% grammatical, as are the cited instances of using *abroad* as a noun. The OED does not find anything remarkable about such usages.

Comment: I like your examples but I get the feeling that they are all more or less humorous in intent so shouldn't be taken as validation for non-standard grammar. They sound a bit like Harry Enfield's Scousers talking about "Going off to that London" to me.

Answer (score -1):

"Abroad" is almost always used as an adverb. For example, l can "study abroad for a semester". When used as a noun, it would only be proper to use it in the sense of " returning from abroad," but not "in/to abroad".